# Problem getting json data via api using PHP

Tags: php, api, cryptocurrency

I have a code in php that gets json data using the Coinbase Pro api, but it shows an error:

```
"file_get_contents (https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products/BTC-USD/stats): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP / 1.1 400 Bad Request ",
```

Sometimes it works for a while, then not again, but when I open the url api in the browser, it works stably, so I don't know where the problem is.

My code:

```
$url = "https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products/BTC-USD/stats";
$fgc = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($fgc, TRUE);
$lastPrice = $json["last"];
$highPrice = $json["high"];
$lowPrice = $json["low"];
$openPrice = $json["open"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You said "sometimes it works for a while, then not again"

That means this is not a PHP or code problem but your API calls are the issue.

Their documentation does mentions that the above feed is public and doesn't requires authentication, so that part is cleared.

Now the error code they have mentioned in their documentation that 400 = Bad Request -- Invalid request format.

The only thing that remains is they are somehow throttling your requests.

Here is a part which mentions that.

"PUBLIC ENDPOINTS
We throttle public endpoints by IP: 3 requests per second, up to 6 requests per second in bursts. Some endpoints may have custom rate limits."

Try to stay within those limits if possible by caching the data on your server side.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I definitely have less requests than 3 per second, it works for a minute, but then for another 10 minutes it doesn't work

Comment: But yes, unfortunately I will probably not solve this problem. Thank you

Comment: They haven't said that for this specific requests they have 3 requests per second. They have left it open to interpretation by mentioning "Some endpoints may have custom rate limits." Try to contact their customer care support only they know which API has how much limit in real.

Answer (score 0):

**What are the rate limits for Coinbase Pro API?**

> REST API
>
> For Public Endpoints, our rate limit is 3 requests per second, up to 6
> requests per second in bursts. For Private Endpoints, our rate limit
> is 5 requests per second, up to 10 requests per second in bursts.

Your code is ok
[check Here for more info](https://help.coinbase.com/en/pro/other-topics/api/faq-on-api)